# (HTML/CSS) How to align a text to middle of center (in both x and y axis)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Welcome!
I got a bit problem while building my first website project.
I have two container(container1,container2(used for two background-image horizontally)).
Now, I want to align the text(h1 element) to the middle of container1 both x and y axis.I want to do it two times(container1 | container2). Finally, I draw an ascii art from it. :)

`***** container1 ***** ****** container2 *****
*                     * *                     *
*   <h1 element 1>    * *   <h1 element 2>    *
*                     * *                     *
*********************** ***********************`

Thank you for help and please,ignore this bad grammar.

Comment: Duplicate question. You can find many questions like this. Just search.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

margin: auto; for vertical align , tex-align:center; for horizontal align

Comment: This is incorrect. `margin: auto;` does not vertically align text.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #center1{
         height:100%;
         display:flex;
         } 

         #center2{
         margin:auto;
         }        
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="center1">
    <span id="center2">Hello</span>    
    </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

This is how you can align text at the center(horizontally and vertically) inside a div.It's working.

Comment: Very nice code, solved my problem. Can you show an example how to align another text below the <span> tag? Can I add some plus/minus pixels to auto property? (LIke: auto-2px) Thank you if you read it.

Comment: you want another text to be exactly under the already present span tag or are you mentioning the design in question?